# Schedule a post with Facebook iOS SDK 3.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook SDK 3.0 on iOS to try to schedule a post to a profile or page. When I try without scheduling, everything goes ok.
However, when I put the following

```
//scheduleDate is a NSDate between the range 10 minutes - 6 months from now
NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [scheduleDate timeIntervalSince1970]];
[requestToPost.parameters setObject:timestamp forKey:@"scheduled_publish_time"];
```

I receive **error 400** and **com.facebook.sdk error 5**.

Anyone have any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that I needed to be aware of two things here:

1 - As Hemang pointed out, the parameter **published** must be defined to NO. So, setting something like `[requestToPost.parameters setObject:@"0" forKey:@"published"];`

or

`[requestToPost.parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"published"];` is mandatory in this case.

2 - From my tests and from the docs, scheduling posts only work for Facebook Pages and not for people (profiles).

Also, it's worth saying again that the date should be between the range 10 minutes - 6 months from 'now'.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is [phasing out](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#offers) scheduled posts for pages.

> Sept 2012: To publish an Offer a corresponding ad must also be created
>   and go live. The parameters `scheduled_publish_time` and `published`
>   parameters are deprecated, and will be silently ignored.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your reply. But it seems that what you posted is related to Offers only. But according to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts they say you can do: *Additionally, Page posts can also be scheduled to go live at a future time up to 6 months*

Comment: Sorry if I was wrong. It was not clear to me that it depreciated for offers only. If that's the case, I would recommend making sure you are also asking for publish_stream and manage_pages permissions and use the latest SDK.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by *Alex L*, reference from [this post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/26/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) dated on, September 27, 2012 that `scheduled_publish_time and published parameters will now be silently ignored.`

However, when you receive error response code `400` it means

> 400 Bad Request. The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax. [Reference Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

One more result on this is [here.](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/409541469083388?browse=search_500884fd030c70b76655054)
`published parameter set to false` should work as said in post.

Something like :

```
[requestToPost.parameters setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE] forKey:@"published"];
```

A detailed response is available [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/304012889695797) seems helpful.

Also found that `scheduled_publish_time` should be in `NSTimeInterval` format. So only numbers between `0-9` would allowed i.e. `1000.0` and `1000` makes difference. You should specified `1000`.

**Updated:**
There's an app [Facebook Pages Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facebook-pages-manager/id514643583?mt=8) having the concept of `scheduled_post`. So there's still possibility of this functionality available by `Facebook`. [Here's a YouTube Video showing the same function](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2r-bPde8Gh0). I hope you would definitely get the solution and will make available to us too. Some more references. [References 1](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/27/featured/schedule-facebook-status-updates.html) [References 2](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/05/31/facebook-allows-post-scheduling-directly-from-pages-without-third-party-tools/) of schedule post allowing apps.

Comment: Hemang, thanks for your reply. Trying to set *published* to **FALSE** didn't help. I also sent the scheduled_publish_time as a int, with no 0 after the comma, and also didn't work. =(

Comment: @NatanR. I've added some information that may help you. Hopefully its still available. You can see the examples apps. However you required deep R&D for it!!